# Sharing asyncio objects between processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am working with both the `asyncio` and the `multiprocessing` library to run two processes, each with one server instance listening on different ports for incoming messages.

To identify each client, I want to share a `dict` between the two processes to update the list of known clients. To achieve this, I decided to use a `Tuple[StreamReader, StreamWriter]` lookup key which is assigned a `Client` object for this connection.

However, as soon as I insert or simply access the shared dict, the program crashes with the following error message:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-5' coro=<GossipServer.handle_client() done, defined at /home/croemheld/Documents/network/server.py:119> exception=AttributeError("Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/croemheld/Documents/network/server.py", line 128, in handle_client
    if not await self.handle_message(reader, writer, buffer):
  File "/home/croemheld/Documents/network/server.py", line 160, in handle_message
    client = self.syncmanager.get_api_client((reader, writer))
  File "<string>", line 2, in get_api_client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 808, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 211, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'
```

Naturally I looked up the error message and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550905/discord-python-bot-attributeerror-cant-pickle-local-object), but I don't really understand what the reason is here. As far as I understand, the reason for this crash is that `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` cannot be pickled/serialized in order to be shared between processes. If that is in fact the reason, is there a way to pickle them, maybe by patching the reducer function to instead use a different pickler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround while also keeping the `asyncio` and `multiprocessing` libraries without any other libraries.

First, since the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects are not pickable, I am forced to use a `socket`. This is easily achievable with a simple function:

```
def get_socket(writer: StreamWriter):
    fileno = writer.get_extra_info('socket').fileno()
    return socket.fromfd(fileno, AddressFamily.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

The socket is inserted into the shared object (e.g. `Manager().dict()` or even a custom class, which you have to register via a custom `BaseManager` instance). Now, since the application is build on `asyncio` and makes use of the streams provided by the library, we can easily convert the `socket` back to a pair of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` via:

```
node_reader, node_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(sock=self.node_sock)
node_writer.write(mesg_text)
await node_writer.drain()
```

Where `self.node_sock` is the `socket` instance that was passed through the shared object.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using [SyncManager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) instead. just be sure to close the manager by calling `shutdown` at the end so no zombie process is left.

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Process
import signal

my_manager = SyncManager()

# to avoid closing the manager by ctrl+C. be sure to handle KeyboardInterrupt errors and close the manager accordingly
def manager_init():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

my_manager.start(manager_init)

my_dict = my_manager.dict()
my_dict["clients"] = my_manager.list()
def my_process(my_id, the_dict):
    for i in range(3):
        the_dict["clients"].append(f"{my_id}_{i}")

processes = []
for j in range(4):
    processes.append(Process(target=my_process, args=(j,my_dict)))

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

print(my_dict["clients"])
# ['0_0', '2_0', '0_1', '3_0', '1_0', '0_2', '1_1', '2_1', '3_1', '1_2', '2_2', '3_2']

my_manager.shutdown()
```

Comment: This does not help since in your code you are simply storing pickable values in the `dict` or `list` you created with `SyncManager`. I am identifying each connection with a `(StreamReader, StreamWriter)` tuple, which are unpickable objects. So my options are limited to either find a way to make them pickable (unlikely) or to use surrogates (pickable keys in the dict) that allow me to obtain the original streams from the `asyncio.start_server()` callback function.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason behind you using StreamReader, StreamWriter is to share the a `dict`. With SyncManager you can share the `dict` that you needed. I'm not sure how the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are used but you can consider initialize choosing something else other than these two classes. maybe [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) is better for the job since their objects are pickable .

Comment: The shared dict is not the problem, its just that the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` objects are not pickable (regardless of the pickler used). I was currently considering if this would work with sockets as well, and while I found out that `socket`s it selves are also not pickable, the file descriptor returned by `socket.fileno()` is (since its just an int). From the file descriptor it should be possible to recreate the original objects, or is the file descriptor unique for the process?

Comment: [socketpair](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socketpair) is pickable. the file descriptor will change after the pickling since it will be in a new process.

Comment: How so? `socket.socketpair()` just returns two sockets which are not pickable. It's not a different class.

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40970286/16617531). I have used socketpair before as an argument to a `Process` function and it worked without issues. I think you are trying to `pickle.dumps(r_socket)` to test if they are pickable. Instead try to use them in multiprocessing function and they will be handled accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236212/discussion-between-croemheld-and-ashley-alfredssons).